# NameError: undefined method 'options' for class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid6, mongodb-3.6

When I create instance of class, Error is raised NameError: undefined method 'options' for class 'Product'.

DB: MongoDB 3.6

```
Class Product
     include Mongoid::Document
     include Mongoid::Timestamps
     include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic

     field :options, type: Hash, default: {}
end
```

gem: mongoid (6.1.1)

NOTE: It works well when I change field name to `option` or anything else, only options Fails. TIA

Comment: `options` is also the name of the 2nd parameter variable in the definition of the `fields()` method.  `:type` and `:default` are gathered into a Hash which is assigned to the `options` parameter variable.  However, there's nothing in the ruby language that prevents you from passing the name of the 2nd parameter variable as an arg to the 1st parameter variable.

Comment: *When I create instance of class, Error is raised*--Are you sure that's all you did?

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/6.1/tutorials/mongoid-documents/index.html#reserved-names):

> **Reserved names**
>
> If you define a field on your document that conflicts with a reserved
> method name in Mongoid, the configuration will raise an error. For a
> list of these you may look at Mongoid.destructive_fields.

Some code from mongoid:

```
# File 'lib/mongoid/config.rb', line 69

def destructive_fields
  Composable.prohibited_methods
end


# File 'lib/mongoid/composable.rb', line 98

def prohibited_methods
  @prohibited_methods ||= MODULES.flat_map do |mod|
    mod.instance_methods.map(&:to_sym)
  end
end
```

`MODULES` constant contains `Fields` module at least which defines `options` method. Maybe it's the reason.